# Managing JOINS in Google Query Language (Google Sheets)

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

I am trying to get a simple recount of how many penalties each user accumulates in my company's website, but avoiding the users that have been deleted (my rows are static, but the new rows added each week have updated user info)

So I have this:

```
penalty_id    date    user    user_status
1             22/09   aaa     active
2             23/09   bbb     active
3             23/09   ccc     active
4             01/10   bbb     active
5             02/10   aaa     deleted
```

And I would like to have this:

```
user     pentaly_count
bbb      2
ccc      1
```

So far I have come up with this

```
=query(Penalties!A:D;"select C, count(A) where D !='deleted' group by C label C 'user', count(A) 'penalty_count'")
```

So I end up with this:

```
user     pentaly_count
bbb      2
aaa      1*
ccc      1
```

The query skips the count of penalty with id 5, but I want it to skip user aaa entirely.

I could have managed this in SQL doing a simple subquery or even a join, but everything I come up with, Google Sheets says it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select C, count(A) 
group by C 
having min(case when D ='deleted' then 1 end) is null
label C 'user', count(A) 'penalty_count'
```